# Excel VBA: More Efficient Way of Removing Rows From Worksheet

Tags: arrays, performance, vba, excel

**Please note the edit after the original function code block**

I've got this data set in Excel that I download from my company's cost management system each month.  On average, this data set is around 100,000 rows with 32 columns.  One of my job functions is to filter out line items that don't belong to my work group and arrange the data in the required format for a separate analysis system.  Typically, I re-arrange the columns, enter a bunch of formulas into cells, and then use a series of autofilter checks to identify line items that need to be moved to other worksheets.  This normally takes me about a couple of hours tops, but it's quite arduous and I'd rather automate the process to save time and reduce chances for me to make mistakes.

So I went ahead and wrote a VBA procedure that satisfies all of the requirements and everything seems to be checking out.  The only problem is that the procedure itself takes about an hour to check 10,000 line items (I stopped it at that point).  Wasting 10 hours watching a progress bar tick is not going to cut it.  So now I'm trying to re-think how I've written this procedure to see if there's a better way (I'm certain there is).

Here's the code as it stands (I omitted a lot of code before and after the main loop for clarity, but I left comments there so you can see what happens in a 'pseudo-code' manner.  The vast majority of time is spent in that loop, so it's really my main concern):

### ORIGINAL FUNCTION

```
Function Prepare_CICTDF()
'Rename and set worksheet
    wbRawFile.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Excluded"
    Set wsSheet = wbRawFile.Worksheets("Excluded")
'Update progress bar
    status_message = "Rearranging columns in CICT Dedicated Facility.  This may take several minutes."
    Call Progress_Bar(current_row, status_message)
'Rearrange columns
    'Omitted to shorten code block
'Create worksheet for included rows
    wbRawFile.Worksheets.Add().Name = "Self Service"
'Copy header row to other worksheets
    wsSheet.Rows("4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Self Service").Range("A4")
'Import Lookup List
    Dim wbLookupList As Workbook
    Set wbLookupList = Workbooks.Open("\\server\path\to\file\Dedicated Facility Lookup List.xlsx")
    Dim wsLookupList As Worksheet
    Set wsLookupList = wbLookupList.Worksheets("Lookup List")
    wsLookupList.Copy Before:=wbRawFile.Worksheets("Excluded")
    wbLookupList.Close SaveChanges:=False
'Get first and last data row
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    FirstRow = 5
    LastRow = wsSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
'Update progress bar
    status_message = "Preparing rows in CICT Dedicated Facilty."
    Call Progress_Bar(current_row, status_message)
'Loop through the rows to add formulas
    Dim NextBlankRow As Long
    Dim RowDeleted As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
        i = FirstRow

    '-------------------------LOOP STARTS HERE-------------------------
    Do While i <= LastRow
        RowDeleted = False
        'Add "CICTDF" before project ID
            wsSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "CICTDF" & wsSheet.Range("B" & i).Text
        'Add formula for "Total Impact" column in column T
            wsSheet.Range("T" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-10]=""Complete"",RC[7]=""Manual Part Number Line Item""),RC[5],IF(AND(RC[-10]=""Complete"",RC[5]=0),0,IF(RC[-10]=""Complete"",RC[5]/RC[-5]*RC[4],RC[5])))"
        'Add formula for rows with blank "Cost Impact - Part" column
            If wsSheet.Range("V" & i).Value = "" Then
                wsSheet.Range("V" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-7]>0,RC[3]/RC[-7]*-1,0)"
            End If
        'Change GLOBAL SUPPLY NETWORK to GLOBAL PURCHASING
            If wsSheet.Range("F" & i).Value = "GLOBAL SUPPLY NETWORK" Then
                wsSheet.Range("F" & i).Value = "GLOBAL PURCHASING"
            End If
        'Change numbers stored as text back to numbers
            wsSheet.Range("M" & i).NumberFormat = "General"
            wsSheet.Range("M" & i).Value = wsSheet.Range("M" & i).Value
            wsSheet.Range("P" & i).NumberFormat = "General"
            wsSheet.Range("P" & i).Value = wsSheet.Range("P" & i).Value
            wsSheet.Range("AB" & i).NumberFormat = "General"
            wsSheet.Range("AC" & i).NumberFormat = "General"
            wsSheet.Range("AD" & i).NumberFormat = "General"
            wsSheet.Range("AE" & i).NumberFormat = "General"
        'Insert Cab Part # Formula
            wsSheet.Range("AB" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(M" & i & ",'Lookup List'!A:A,1,FALSE)"
        'Insert Cabs DC formula
            wsSheet.Range("AC" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(N" & i & ",'Lookup List'!B:B,1,FALSE)"
        'Insert Cab Localization HEX & MG Formula
            wsSheet.Range("AD" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B" & i & ",'Lookup List'!C:C,1,FALSE)"
        'Insert Already in MOASS formula
            wsSheet.Range("AE" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B" & i & ",'Lookup List'!D:D,1,FALSE)"
        'Include part numbers that match the inclusion criteria
            If wsSheet.Range("AB" & i).Text <> "#N/A" And wsSheet.Range("AC" & i).Text = "#N/A" And wsSheet.Range("AD" & i).Text = "#N/A" _
            And wsSheet.Range("AE" & i).Text = "#N/A" And wsSheet.Range("P" & i).Value = "14" Then
                NextBlankRow = Worksheets("Self Service").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                    wsSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Self Service").Range("A" & NextBlankRow)
                    wsSheet.Rows(i).Delete
                RowDeleted = True
            End If
        'Check if the row was included or not
            If RowDeleted = True Then
                LastRow = LastRow - 1
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        'Update the progress completion
            current_row = current_row + 1
            Call Progress_Bar(current_row, status_message)
    Loop
    '-------------------------LOOP STOPS HERE-------------------------

'Autofilter header row in Self Service tab
    Worksheets("Self Service").Range("B4:AG4").AutoFilter
'Save as new file format
    Worksheets("Self Service").Select
    wbRawFile.SaveAs Filename:=output_directory & "CICT 2014 Dedicated Facility.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    wbRawFile.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbRawFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Function
```

Basically I loop through all of the lines in the file.  For each line, I enter the formulas and values that I need and then check if they satisfy the inclusion requirements.  If they do, I move the line to the "Self Service" worksheet, delete the line from the "Excluded" worksheet, and move on to the next line.

After running the first 10,000 lines of data, the elapsed time was just over 58 minutes.  I think most of this can be attributed to the copy/paste/delete processes at the tail end of the loop.  I've read that a common suggestion is to work within arrays instead of manipulating cells/rows/ranges in Excel, but I'm not exactly sure how I would go about doing this.

## ----------Edit:----------

After some input from Ron Rosenfeld, I revisited my process a little bit and made a bunch of changes.  In the end, the new procedure processes and prepares over 100,000 rows (of 32 columns) in just over 49 minutes.  The original procedure would have taken over 9.75 hours, so the changes have resulted in a procedure that's over 10x faster than its predecessor.  Rather than paste the entire code block again, I'll describe the procedure in "pseudo-code":

1. Rearrange columns (takes the raw server download and puts it in the order I need).
2. Create a new worksheet for the included rows.  Note that for my purposes, I process over 100,000 rows but end up keeping only about 10,000.  Thus, I made the decision to look for those that I would INCLUDE instead of those that I would EXCLUDE.
3. Enter formulas in first row of data and drag down the column.  I used Ron's suggestion of e.g. `Range("A" & FirstRow & ":A" & LastRow") = "=B1+C1"` for any columns that I could.
4. There was one column that only needed formulas if the cell was blank.  So I used the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` method to enter these.
5. AutoFiltered the data so that only the rows I wanted to include were visible.  Again I used the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` method to find these and stored them in an array.  This array was then entered into the new worksheet.
6. Finally, I did a little bit of massaging format-wise to make sure everything looked consistent (since storing the values in the array lost the cell formats).

It should also be noted that I think Tim's suggestion of using SQL in this scenario could be a very efficient alternative--I simply wasn't versed well enough on the topic to try it out.  I'll be looking for ways to use it in the future, though!

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: To copy a row you would loop through each column.  To enter formulas you will need to address the destination cells directly.  However, if you have, for example, a column of formulas that are the same, but the address is relative, you could write the column with one operation:  e.g. A1: =B1+C1 and you want this to fill down 100 rows; then use Range("A1:A100") = "=B1+C1"  and it will adjust for each row to B2+C2  etc.

Comment: Also, in your code, it would be faster to get the number of Rows and Columns with  numRawRows = ubound(arrRawData,1): numColumns = ubound(arrRawData,2)

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the quick reply!  Do you think I would realize any significant performance increase by mixing the two methods?  For example, your comment made me think about entering all of the formulas and the like by looping through the rows in the worksheet (like I already have it in the original post).  But then I'd copy the data to an array, loop through the arrays to move the rows, and finally print the arrays back onto the worksheet.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Without knowing the exact layout of your worksheets, it is hard to say.  In general, with regard to values, the process of reading a large DB into an array; looping through the array to decide what rows/items to keep, the writing that back to a new sheet, is usually at least an order of magnitude (10x) faster than looping through rows.  Sometimes a challenge is to figure out how big the results array needs to be.  If that cannot be done with some simple formulas, I have taken the interim step of gathering each row into a collection before dimensioning the results array.

Comment: The formulas add another dimension, but look at handling it as I suggested in my first comment.  It may be that you can develop a database of formulas that you will apply to certain columns. In that case, you would not need to loop through rows at all (or maybe just a single row to see where the formula are), then write the formulas in a single operation to all the cells in a particular column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks for the advice.  I'll go ahead and make some changes this afternoon and see what I can come up with.  I'll let you know the results.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld see my edit to the original post.  I've separated the function into two separate processes: one for looping through all of the rows and adding in the formulas, and the other for moving the data to arrays, looping through the arrays, and putting the required rows in the other worksheet.  Now, I'm getting an 'Out of Memory' error on the line that I ReDim `arrIncluded`.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to loop through **all** the rows to write the formulas? Also, if you are going to be excluding some rows, why are you declaring arrIncluded to be the same size as arrRawData?  Shouldn't it be smaller?  Finally, you will need to add the formulas AFTER you write the values, using the array method, to the worksheet.  If, after reading the data into arrRawData, and declaring arrIncluded to be of the proper size, you are still getting out of memory, you may have to do it in chunks.

Comment: Another thought after looking at your code:  why not just filter on the values for columns 15, 27-30, and then copy/paste the visible cells to your new worksheet. And put the formulas into the desired columns in a single step?  I don't know if the autofilter would be faster on this size DB, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Good thoughts--I'll try to address them in the order you presented them.  The main reason that I loop through all of the rows to enter the formulas is that some of the formulas only get entered if the cell is blank.  For instance, if the part number has a cost associated, I keep that cost.  If not, I use a formula to estimate it.  The other formulas get applied to every cell in the column.  Is there a better way to address this case?

I can't add the formulas AFTER I write values to the worksheet because I use the formulas to determine which rows to write, if that makes sense.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're entirely correct about the size of arrIncluded--it should be much smaller (roughly 8,000ish rows out of 100,000+) than arrRawData.  However, when declaring the array, I believe I have to make it bigger than it needs to be and then shrink it down after, correct?  E.g. since I can't ReDim the array each time I find a new row to include, it needs to be large enough to hold all of the rows from the get-go.  Is there a better way to be accomplishing that?

Comment: @TomWinchester - have you considered using SQL? it's designed for dealing with large record volumes in ways that Excel is not:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Finally, I wasn't aware that I could use AutoFilter from within a VBA procedure.  I knew I could set the filter criteria, but how would I know which row numbers meet the criteria so I know which ones to copy?  If I tell it to copy all rows from 5:100000 it will copy all of them, even if I have the AutoFilter set, right?  I honestly didn't consider this a possibility, so I'll start playing with this first thing in the morning and see what I can come up with.  It would be perfect if it works--I used AutoFilter when I did it by hand.  Thanks again for all of your help today!

Comment: @Tim - About halfway through the development of this function I thought to myself that SQL would be a better way to handle this data set.  I've used SQL in some web applications but I'm by no means an expert.  I'll read that source over and see if I can learn how to apply it to my situation.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TomWinchester - yes worth checking out for your case I think, here is a great walk-through of the main techniques required:
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=217783

Comment: @TomWinchester Answering your points in order: After you write the data to the worksheet; you can select all the blanks in the range with the SpecialCells method and write the formula that way: R.columns(X).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[1] + RC[2]".  To get the size of arrIncluded, it seems you could either use CountIfs; or you could add the desired rows to a Collection, then use the Count property to get the size of arrIncluded; and write the Collection to the array.  I prefer the Collection method, but test to see which way is faster.

Comment: @TomWinchester For AutoFilter, see VBA Help, and also use the Macro Recorder.  To copy the result, use the SpecialCells method to select just the visible cells  R.SpecialCells(xlcelltypevisible).copy Destination

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Alright so I've finally got everything working at a much faster pace than my original procedure.  I ended up mixing in a lot of the suggestions that you provided (using formula dragging instead of looping where possible and using AutoFilter/SpecialCells to store specific rows in an array instead of looping through each row were the biggest players).  In total, my procedure now averages about 49 minutes to process and prepare over 100,000 rows--that's more than 10x faster than the original.  Is there a way to select an answer so you get credit for it if it's in a comment?

Comment: @TomWinchester Thank you. I'll put my comments into an Answer.  Glad to hear that you've got things running much more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact layout of your worksheets, it is hard to say. In general, with regard to values, the process of reading a large DB into an array; looping through the array to decide what rows/items to keep, the writing that back to a new sheet, is usually at least an order of magnitude (10x) faster than looping through rows. Sometimes a challenge is to figure out how big the results array needs to be. If that cannot be done with some simple formulas, I have taken the interim step of gathering each row into a collection before dimensioning the results array.

Another thought after looking at your code: why not just filter on the values for columns 15, 27-30, and then copy/paste the visible cells to your new worksheet.

After you write the data to the worksheet; you can select all the blanks in the range with the SpecialCells method and write the formula that way:

```
R.columns(X).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[1] + RC[2]".
```

To get the size of arrIncluded, it seems you could either use CountIfs; or you could add the desired rows to a Collection, then use the Count property to get the size of arrIncluded; and write the Collection to the array. I prefer the Collection method, but test to see which way is faster.